# How to create a duplex connection using TcpListener and TcpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcp, network-programming

I have a situation where I need to send and receive information parallelly.
My protocol can define a read port and a write port.

I currently have the following code:

```
public void Listen()
{
    ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(50, 50);
    listener.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        var context = new ListeningContext(listener.AcceptTcpClient(), WritePort);
    }
}
```

How can I create another listener from the TcpClient I am passing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A `TcpClient` object wraps a `NetworkStream` object.  You use the `GetStream()` method of `TcpClient` to access the `NetworkStream` object, which is then used to read data from and write data to the network.  The MSDN article for [`NetworkStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx) says the following:

> Read and write operations can be
>   performed simultaneously on an
>   instance of the NetworkStream class
>   without the need for synchronization.
>   As long as there is one unique thread
>   for the write operations and one
>   unique thread for the read operations,
>   there will be no cross-interference
>   between read and write threads and no
>   synchronization is required.

Use the `TcpListener` object to listen for incoming connections.  Use the `TcpClient` object returned from the call to `AcceptTcpClient()` to communicate (read *and* write) with the remote endpoint.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for. Thank you. So that means I can't use the TaskFactory? It might run operations on the same thread.

Comment: Long story short how can I gaurentee that read and write both run on different threads with the Task API?

Answer (score 4):

TCP connection is a **full-duplex pipe**, take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol). You don't need a separate port or anything else.

Comment: As far as I know you can only send or receive because the socket might be a file right? I can't find where it says that it's full duplex.

Comment: No, sockets are sockets, files are files.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: Linux implements sockets using file descriptors. Am I missing something?

Comment: Not only Linux, sockets are represented as file descriptors everywhere. You cannot call `accept()` on a regular disk file though. The kernel knows the difference.

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: I didn't say it's a regular file. It uses the hard drivce right?

Comment: File descriptor is the offset into process open file table that references kernel file table that holds function pointers to processing routines. Those are different for each file system, and for sockets, and for shared memory segments, etc. And no, sockets do not use hard drives, that'd be painfully slow networking :)